# CompletableFuture wrapper

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, completable-future

I have async method

```
asyncClass.getChild("test", listChild -> {
  if (listChild.isOk()) {
  List<String> list = listChild.isSuccess().getData()
  }
  return null;
});
```

How I can wrap this async call in CompletableFuture?

```
final CompletableFuture<List<String>> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
asyncClass.getChild("test", listChild -> {
  if (listChild.isOk()) {
    future.complete(listChild.isSuccess().getData());
  }
  return null;
});
return future;
```

Everything works fine, but I want everything to work in a separate thread calls

```
interface AsyncFS {
    fun getChild(path: String, onResult: (Result<List<String>>) -> Unit)
}
```

Comment: What does the method `asyncClass.getChild` return? Is it void? And what's the problem with how you've implemented it (second snippet)?

Comment: Yes it's void. All data information exists in listChild

Comment: I add interface asyncClass

Comment: Is your interface in Kotlin? If so, why don't you try coroutines?

Comment: It's small test, I must realse it on CompletableFuture  and RxJava

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `asyncClass.getChild` is executed asynchronously (as it takes a callback). If that's the case, then your current implementation is enough (except for the correction below).

```
asyncClass.getChild("test", listChild -> {
  if (listChild.isOk()) {
    future.complete(listChild.isSuccess().getData());
  } else {
      future.complete(null); //you need to do this
      //or future.completeExceptionally(exception) if this is a failure
  }
});
```

If you want `getChild` to run in a separate thread, then I'd strongly suggest you redesign the method to make it return `List<String>` instead of taking a callback. This design makes it awkward to run `getChild` asynchronously.

```
interface AsyncFS {
    fun getChild(path: String): List<String> //don't trust my syntax
}
```

And then run it asynchronously in this way:

```
CompletableFuture<List<String>> future = 
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> asyncClass.getChild("test"));
return future;
```

Comment: fun getChild(path: String): List<String>  - How will I return data if there is a delay?

Comment: @LeshaRB that's for the case where it simply blocks and only return after the time it takes. But all that time is spent asynchronously by virtue of the `supplyAsync`

Comment: @LeshaRB Remember, that's an alternative approach. If `getCild` is already asynchronous, then look at top part of this answer

Answer (score 0):

Supply a Runnable or Supplier as an argument to `CompletableFuture.runAsync()` or `supplyAsync()`

```
return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    doSomething();
}, optionalExecutor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `getChild()` method to return a `CompletableFuture<ListChild>` instead of taking a callback as parameter.

Without the actual code, I cannot tell exactly how this must be done, but basically the code would look like

```
CompletableFuture<ListChild> result = new CompletableFuture<>();
processAsynchronously(path, result);
return result;
```

where `processAsynchronously()` performs the asynchronous computation, and at some point calls `result.complete(listChild)`.

The caller will then be able to easily chain calls like

```
CompletableFuture<List<String>> result = asyncClass.getChild("test")
          .thenAcceptAsync(listChild -> {
              if (listChild.isOk()) {
                  return listChild.isSuccess().getData()
              }
              return null;
          }, executor);
```

or any other processing using any executor he wants.

As you see, this will be much more flexible than forcing a particular type of callback.